# Gas pedal suddenly not giving power to my car

Tags: engine, mitsubishi, lancer

I have a 2006 Mitsubishi Lancer.I was driving about 110 km/hr and then my car started to lose speed. I was pressing on the gas pedal but it was like it lost the ability to work. My battery light and a light that is an exclamation went on. I pulled over, turned off the car and turned it back on. Everything seemed fine and the lights were off so I started to speed up again. Then it happened again so I had it towed to my mechanic. He is on vacation and I am curious what it could be. Just looking for some answers.

Comment: Which engine in your Lancer?

Comment: I don't know...I don't have the manual with me to check

Comment: Events like this should be stored by the engine computer as faults or error codes. My recommended course of action is to hook it up to a code scanner that should be able to tell you what happened. Once you do this we'd be happy to help you out with what we think is wrong